# What version of Kylin should I use with HDP 2.4?

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, kylin

So I have installed HDP 2.4 and I know want to install Kylin. On the website there are binaries for hbase 1.1.3+ or 0.99 but I have hbase 1.1.2 (installed by Ambari 2.2.1). I have tried several ones and the best case I have is no errors when launching `bin/kylin.sh start` and no logs but the web page is blank (no error, just blank).

So what version should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a package for HBase 1.x on the download page. Pick that one.

[1] http://kylin.apache.org/download/